# FloatingActionButton not hiding when scrolling down using com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionButton library

Tags: java, android

When scroll happens the floatingaction button needs to go down/hide. But its not happening. It just stays in same position. As per the sample provided its demonstrating for listview but I am using RecyclerView.

I am using https://github.com/Clans/FloatingActionButton

**Xml layout code**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:fab="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/swipeContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recyclerViewSubscription"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/color_white" />

    </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

    <com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_action_new"
        fab:fab_colorNormal="@color/button_color"
        fab:fab_colorPressed="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        fab:fab_colorRipple="@color/colorPrimary"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Java Code**

```
 int mPreviousVisibleItem;

recyclerViewSubscription = (RecyclerView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.recyclerViewSubscription);
floatingActionButton = (FloatingActionButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.fab);

RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
recyclerViewSubscription.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
recyclerViewSubscription.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());

floatingActionButton.hide(false);
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                floatingActionButton.show(true);
                floatingActionButton.setShowAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(), R.anim.show_from_bottom));
                floatingActionButton.setHideAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(), R.anim.hide_to_bottom));
            }
        }, 300);

        recyclerViewSubscription.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount) {
                if (firstVisibleItem > mPreviousVisibleItem) {
                    floatingActionButton.hide(true);
                } else if (firstVisibleItem < mPreviousVisibleItem) {
                    floatingActionButton.show(true);
                }
                mPreviousVisibleItem = firstVisibleItem;
            }
        });
```

**show_from_bottom xml file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:interpolator/accelerate_cubic"
    android:fromYDelta="30%p"
    android:toYDelta="0"
    android:duration="300" />
```

**hide_to_bottom xml file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:interpolator/accelerate_quint"
    android:fromYDelta="0"
    android:toYDelta="30%p"
    android:duration="200" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you check this
[Behavior](https://gist.github.com/mmazzarolo/7cf95a345bd8a59c0722)
And check that CoordinatorLayout is the **first parent** of your FAB menu